# How can I sign a string using RSA and SHA256 in a react native expo managed app?

Tags: react-native, expo, rsa, sign

I need to sign a string using rsa-sha256, but I have not found a way to do it successfully yet in my react native expo managed app. I have tried an example in node.js with success, but the dependences of this example are not compatible with an expo managed app.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.